# function inside another function doesn't execute in JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my current project, I have a function which calls an angular custom service and assign the data to a variable

```
var vm = this;
vm.itemname = '';

function getItems(){
  var result = myservice.getFromLibrary();
  result.then(function(data){
     vm.dataSet = data;
  });
}
```

I have another function to save the data and after it get saved the getItem() function should be called, as follows

```
vm.addItem = function(){
    var newItem = {"title": vm.itemname};
    myservice.setToLibrary(newItem);
    getItems();
};
```

but when the vm.addItem called, it doesn't retrieve the items in getItems function but it gives me an undefined output

Any help will be highly appreciated to fix this issue

Comment: Add item doesn't return anything, so it should be undefined.

Comment: Not sure if it is relevant, besides the getItems !== getitem issue with the code you posted, but `myservice.getFromLibrary();` is obviously asynchronous so, `vm.dataSet` wont be set until "some time after" the call to `vm.addItem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I you call the function name wrong, `getItem` should be `getItems`.

If it is a typo, call the getItems method after the promise is returned from the service.

You can even add the error function from the callback.

When you use this `promise(then and error)`, the next lines of code executes only when the response comes from the service.

```
vm.addItem = function(){
    var newItem = {"title": vm.itemname};
    myservice.setToLibrary(newItem)
    .then(function(response){
        getItem();
    }
    function error(response) 
    {
     console.log('error')
    });
};
```

Comment: Hi @Sravan, Thanks a lot for the reply. Yes it works. The issue was in the service file as I tried earlier this approach, I got an error saying `then` is not defined, but when I checked in the service file, it wasn't returning a promise, I fixed it there as well. Now it works perfectly. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

The function name is `getItems()` but when you are calling it from `addItem`, you are calling an undefined function `getItem()` - the `s` is missing in the name of the function you are trying to call.

Comment: thanks for pointing it out, its a typo when I wrote it, its not in the actual code

Answer (score 0):

If I'm assuming right you are adding an item through service call `myservice.setToLibrary(newItem);` and after that reading the item present in DB through `getItems();` which is again a service call i.e `$http POST or GET`.

**Reason behind the 'undefined' output**

As you can see in your `vm.addItem()` function you are doing two `$http` calls to add and read.As `$http` is asynchronous in nature,your `getItems()` is executed before even your `myservice.setToLibrary(newItem)` is completely executed.

Due to this you are getting an undefined output.

**Solution approach**

Make some adjustments in your `vm.addItem()` function like below

```
vm.addItem = function(){
    var newItem = {"title": vm.itemname};
    myservice.setToLibrary(newItem).success(function(data){
        getItems();
    });
```

This approach will get you desired result as we made our `getItems()` call after the success of our `setToLibrary()` call.

Comment: Thanks for the short clear explanation, I tried @Sravan's answer and it worked for me.